# How to correct when Accuracy equals F1 in Torch Lightning for binary classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning, pytorch-geometric

I understand that with multi-class, [F1 (micro) is the same as Accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358496/is-f1-micro-the-same-as-accuracy). I aim to test a binary classification in Torch Lightning but always get identical F1, and Accuracy.

To get more detail, I shared my code at [GIST](https://gist.github.com/dongchirua/71c6c02c71d580664dcea4e512c05198), where I used the [MUTAG](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notes/data_cheatsheet.html) dataset. Below are some important parts I would like to bring up for discussion

The function where I compute Accuracy and F1 (line #28-40)

```
def evaluate(self, batch, stage=None):
        y_hat = self(batch.x, batch.edge_index, batch.batch)
        loss = self.criterion(y_hat, batch.y)
        preds = torch.argmax(y_hat.softmax(dim=1), dim=1)
        acc = accuracy(preds, batch.y)
        f1_score = f1(preds, batch.y)

        if stage:
            self.log(f"{stage}_loss", loss, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, logger=True)
            self.log(f"{stage}_acc", acc, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, logger=True)
            self.log(f"{stage}_f1", f1_score, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, logger=True)

        return loss
```

To inspect, I put a checkpoint at line #35, and got `acc=0.5`, `f1_score=0.5`, while `prediction` and `label` respectively are

```
preds = tensor([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0])
batch.y = tensor([1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
```

Using these values, I run a notebook to double-check with `scikit-learn`

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_hat = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
y = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
f1_score(y_hat, y, average='binary') # got 0.6153846153846153
accuracy_score(y_hat, y) # 0.5
```

I obtained a different result compared to evaluation's code. Besides, I verified again with `torch`, interestingly, I got a correct result

```
from torchmetrics.functional import accuracy, f1
import torch
f1(torch.Tensor(y_hat), torch.LongTensor(y)) # tensor(0.6154)
accuracy(torch.Tensor(pred), torch.LongTensor(true)) # tensor(0.5000)
```

I guess somehow the `torch-lightning` treats my calculation as a multiclass task. My question is how to correct its behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `multiclass=False` in case your dataset is binary.

This will give you the result which matches the Sklearn F1 score output where `average="binary"` (default) is passed.

> [We can set multiclass=False to treat the inputs as binary - which is the same as converting the predictions to float beforehand.](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pages/classification.html#using-the-multiclass-parameter)

#### Sklearn results

```py
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, accuracy_score

y_hat = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
y =     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]


print("Binary f1: ", f1_score(y, y_hat, average="binary"))  # default
print("Micro f1:", f1_score(y, y_hat, average="micro"))  # this is same as accuracy
print("accuracy_score", accuracy_score(y, y_hat))

>>> Binary f1: 0.6153846153846153
>>> Micro f1: 0.5
>>> accuracy_score: 0.5
```

##### Pytorch-Lightning Results

```py
import torchmetrics.functional as F
import torch

y_hat = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
y =     [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

# torchmetrics
print("Non-Multiclass f1: ", F.f1_score(torch.tensor(y), torch.tensor(y_hat), multiclass=False))
print("Multiclass f1:", F.f1_score(torch.tensor(y), torch.tensor(y_hat))) # same as accuracy
print("accuracy_score", F.accuracy(torch.tensor(y), torch.tensor(y_hat)))

>>> Non-Multiclass f1: tensor(0.6154)
>>> Multiclass f1: tensor(0.5000)
>>> accuracy_score tensor(0.5000)
```