# Sklearn evaluate accuracy, precision, recall, f1 show same result

Tags: python, scikit-learn, evaluation

I want to evaluate with accuracy, precision, recall, f1 like this code but it show same result.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'test.csv')

X = df.iloc[:,:10]
Y = df.iloc[:,10]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

predictions = clf.predict(X_test)

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
precision = precision_score(y_test, predictions,average='micro')
recall = recall_score(y_test, predictions,average='micro')
f1 = f1_score(y_test, predictions,average='micro')

print("Accuracy: ", accuracy)
print("precision: ", precision)
print("recall: ", recall)
print("f1: ", f1)
```

It show output like this.

```
Accuracy:  0.8058823529411765
precision:  0.8058823529411765
recall:  0.8058823529411765
f1:  0.8058823529411765
```

The output is same value. How to fix it?

Comment: This should be some error in your code, try to find it or provide full code.

Comment: I provide full code already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to sklearn's [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification), the behavior is expected when using `micro` as average and when dealing with a multiclass setting:

> Note that if all labels are included, “micro”-averaging in a
> multiclass setting will produce precision, recall and F that are all
> identical to accuracy.

Here is a nice [blog article](https://simonhessner.de/why-are-precision-recall-and-f1-score-equal-when-using-micro-averaging-in-a-multi-class-problem/) describing why these scores can be equal (also with an intuitive example)

**TL;DR**

1. `F1` equals `recall` and `precision` if `recall` == `precision`
2. In the case of micro averaging, the number of false positive always equals the number of false negative. Thus, `recall` == `precision`
3. Finally, note that `micro F1` always equals `accuracy`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358496/is-f1-micro-the-same-as-accuracy)