# Torchmetrics Multiclass F1Score same results as Accuracy

Tags: pytorch, torchmetrics

I am trying to log several metrics over my unbalanced classification dataset using the `MetricTracker` of the `torchmetrics` library. I find that the results for `Precision` `Recall` and `F1Score` always equal to the `Accuracy` even though it should not.

A minimal example of how to produce this behaviour would look like this:

```
import torch
import torchmetrics
from torchmetrics import MetricTracker, MetricCollection
from torchmetrics import Accuracy, F1Score, Precision, Recall, CohenKappa

num_classes = 3

list_of_metrics = [Accuracy(task="multiclass", num_classes=num_classes),
                   F1Score(task="multiclass", num_classes=num_classes),
                   Precision(task="multiclass",num_classes=num_classes),
                   Recall(task="multiclass",num_classes=num_classes),
                   CohenKappa(task="multiclass",num_classes=num_classes)
                   ]

maximize_list=[True,True,True,True,True]

metric_coll = MetricCollection(list_of_metrics)
tracker = MetricTracker(metric_coll, maximize=maximize_list)


pred = torch.Tensor([[0,.1,.5], # 2
                     [0,.1,.5],  # 2
                     [0,.1,.5],  # 2
                     [0,.1,.5],  # 2
                     [0,.1,.5],  # 2
                     [0.9,.1,.5]]) # 0

label = torch.Tensor([2,2,2,2,2,1])

tracker.increment()
tracker.update(pred, label)

for key, val in tracker.compute_all().items():
    print(key,val)
```

Output:

```
MulticlassAccuracy tensor([0.8333])
MulticlassF1Score tensor([0.8333])
MulticlassPrecision tensor([0.8333])
MulticlassRecall tensor([0.8333])
MulticlassCohenKappa tensor([0.4545])
```

Does anyone know what is the problem here and how to fix it?

I use version `0.11.1` of the`torchmetrics` library.

Comment: This discussion might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358496/is-f1-micro-the-same-as-accuracy

Comment: No I think it's a bug in torchmetrics or some gotcha that isn't obvious from their tutorial. I have this in torchmetrics 1.2.1 and have for a while, which is why I want to love this library but instead avoid it. I just implemented a new pipeline, hoping it would work, but accuracy = precision = recall = fmeasure, and that's macro not micro.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's a [documentation bug](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/torchmetrics/issues/2280).

The fix is always explicitly to state what 'average' you want.